# ArgumentError Exception: absolute URL needed Mechanize link_with click

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri, mechanize, watir

I am using Watir and Mechanize to do some web scraping and currently running into some issues.

In my code i do the following

```
loaded_page = Watir::Browser.new(:chrome, {:chromeOptions => {:args => ['--headless', '--window-size=1200x600']}})
loaded_page.goto 'http://localhost:8080/page1.html'
```

I generate my mechanize page as follows

```
agent = Mechanize.new
page = Mechanize::Page.new(nil, {'content-type'=>'text/html'}, loaded_page.html, nil, agent)
```

i have the following Page::Link list

```
#<Mechanize::Page::Link
   "AB: 2-Litre Drink"
   "/abas-read/a-b-a-r-litre-drink">
#<Mechanize::Page::Link "and more" "#">
```

On the page when i click on the hyperlink `and more` it opens up a pop up. So in my code with Mechanize i am trying to trigger that link to be clicked. So i do this

```
page.link_with(text: 'and more').click
```

But i then get the error

```
ArgumentError Exception: absolute URL needed (not #)
```

Not quite sure how to deal with this error and why it is not treating the url as absolute url.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Mechanize, so I can't speak to that error without guessing, but I'm interested in your use case for needing to combine Watir & Mechanize.

Comment: Absolute url means it starts with `http` or `https`. That one starts with `/` which makes it relative.